# Windows plesk migration

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, database-migration, plesk

We had a Plesk-Windows server and due to hardware issues DC copied contents of the hardisk to another stable disk and reconnected to the server using USB. Now the IIS and plesk seems like a freshly installed one, with no accounts configured in them.

How would I migrate the contents from this server to a new Windows-plesk Server?
Plesk version 11/ Windows 2008 on both servers

I am new to migration in windows. And I am really stuck here. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you any backups in old Plesk? Anyway I suggest you to send private message to IgorG from Parallels staff on parallels forum http://forum.parallels.com/member.php?90711-IgorG. Describe situation to him, maybe you have to provide server credentials.  Unfortunately it difficult to advice something without looking on server.

Answer (score 0):

//Have you any backups in old Plesk?

We have plesk backup files, but it fails to restore. Shows error : package not found and some privilege errors.

Answer (score 0):

If plesk backup files are not getting restored the only way left out is to manually create the sites from Plesk panel and then copy the contents, databases etc from the backup.